# What is the proper way to access an adjacent Python package without setting PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pip, conda

When developing in my IDE, I can access adjacent packages like `foo.a` from `foo.b`, since `foo` is beneath the IDE's content root (the IDE adds to PYTHONPATH).

However, once the project is deployed, my import statements fail.

Since, I should not set PYTHONPATH (according to [anaconda's documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#resolution-for-python-packages-make-sure-you-do-not-have-pythonpath-or-pythonhome-set)), what is the appropriate way to reference an adjacent package? Is this best solved by deployment (setup.py), or some other means?

Notes:

- I use the conda package manager to create virtual environments (this question may also apply to virtualenv).
- I'm using Python 3

Comment: How is the project deployed, and how is it used?  If the path to the top-level package `foo` is on the path, then relative imports should work fine.  If not, people won't be able to import `foo` anyway, so you should probably make it so `foo` gets put on the path.

Comment: Add them to `os.path` at run time maybe?

Comment: @BrenBarn on a single test server, `git clone` "installed" the source

Comment: @BrianBien: That doesn't really install it, it just copies the files.  You should look into using `setup.py` to make your code installable, for instance via `pip`.  A "real" install will add your package to the appropriate paths.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yeah I know (hence the quotes). I did try pip install -e . (install from source) to no avail. It sounds like pip install might be the solution, but I just didn't get the configuration correct.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you need to ask a more specific question where you provide details about how the install fails and what your setup.py looks like.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks. You sound pretty confident, so I'll research and retry this approach and follow up